# Sum the digits of a number in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns an integer number from a mathematical calculation. I need to sum all the digits in that integer number.

Something like this:

```
select sumdigits(number) from dual
-- if number =123, output: 1+2+3 = 6 
-- if number =100, output: 1+0+0 = 1
```

Comment: check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671921/mysql-query-for-sum-and-distinct?rq=1

Comment: Is the width of the number fixed, e.g. always 3 digits?  I think in the general case you'd want a UDF for this.

Comment: OP wants to take the digits and sum them. So make the numer 123 into 1, 2 and 3

Comment: @juergend: exactly, but how do I separate the number into digits?

Comment: @FreudianSlip As does 1+2+3, so what does that prove?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes the numbe is fixed, or at least I can zero pad it.

Comment: @Lamar Why do you want to do this in MySQL?

Comment: @Strawberry because it's part of a bigger query.

Comment: Well, maybe tell us about that.

Comment: @Strawberry I wanted to be focused on the main problem here, not distract people with irrelevant info.

Comment: It sounds like it might be relevant

Comment: @Strawberry sorry if that caused you confusion. Anyway, back to the main question :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález All integers.

Comment: A pity that you were looking for the digit sum and not the digital root (the repeated digital sum where you end up with a single digit), for this would simply have been `number % 9` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to test this using Fiddle or Rextester, but neither is working right now.  So, your upvotes/downvotes will serve as the test:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(number, 1, 1) AS UNSIGNED) +              -- first digit
       CAST(SUBSTRING(number, 2, 1) AS UNSIGNED) +              -- second digit
       CAST(SUBSTRING(number, 3, 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS the_sum     -- third digit
FROM yourTable
```

This assumes a number with a max width of 3 digits, which is also zero padded (as you mentioned we can assume).

If you really need to do this in production, you should probably create a user defined function to handle such manipulations, edge cases, etc.

**Update:**

Going with the comment by @ThorstenKettner we could generalize this answer to a `number` field of *any* length by just adding more terms for each digit position.  For example, if we wanted to cover numbers which could be up to four digits wide we could just add this term:

```
+ CAST(SUBSTRING(number, 4, 1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

which would either add a number if present, or would add zero if not present.

Comment: @Lamar Well downvote me if you want to see my other half LOL :-P

Comment: Seriously, I'm tired of smarta$$ people who only give negative feedback instead of providing solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't take that completely personally, a lot of it was just concern about scope, edge cases, etc.  Happy to help you though.

Comment: @Lamar You haven't received any negative feedback, just reasonable questions to understand the problem. You should not be so obsessed with just implementing blindly a solution you've figured out—pretty often there's a simpler solution to the actual problem. And, sure, this may not be one of those cases, but we have no way to know.

Comment: `number` wouldn't even have to get zero-padded beforehand. If `SUBSTRING` finds nothing at a given position then it returns the empty string '' which `CAST AS UNSIGNED` converts to zero.

Answer (score 3):

I'm ashamed to even suggest this but...

```
SELECT
    foo,
    CHAR_LENGTH(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            REPLACE(
                                                REPLACE(foo, '-', ''),
                                            '0', ''),
                                        '1', '1'),
                                    '2', '22'),
                                '3', '333'),
                            '4', '4444'),
                        '5', '55555'),
                    '6', '666666'),
                '7', '7777777'),
            '8', '88888888'),
        '9', '999999999')
    ) AS digit_sum
FROM (
     SELECT 123 AS foo
     UNION ALL SELECT 100
     UNION ALL SELECT 413432143
     UNION ALL SELECT -6301
     UNION ALL SELECT 1234567890
) x
```

> ```
> +------------+-----------+
> | foo        | digit_sum |
> +------------+-----------+
> |        123 |         6 |
> |        100 |         1 |
> |  413432143 |        25 |
> |      -6301 |        10 |
> | 1234567890 |        45 |
> +------------+-----------+
> 5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

It probably makes more sense rewritten as function, together with some error checking to return `NULL` on floats or something similar.

Comment: Well, even if this is painful to propose (as I can imagine) this is a "good" idea.

Comment: Extending it to hexadecimal digits is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)